# Change Keyboard Layout without losing another keybinds

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, i3-wm

To switch between the layout, using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, I use this command :

```bash
setxkbmap -layout "us,ara" -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
```

But, When I use some `keys` like <kbd>Left</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> it's will change the layout, but I don't want to switch to next layout now,

#### How can I prevent to switch between layout when I use more than two keys?

I'm using the `dwm` or `i3`… as **windows manager**, not the `gnome` **desktop**

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I think ALT+Shift also conflicts with EMacs shortcuts. You can change `-option` from [this list](https://gist.github.com/Spoygg/3122226) start with `grp:` Or you can register the new shortcut for it.

Comment: thank's, the `grp:alt_shift_toggle` is work fun when use `alt`+`shift` only, but also work when i use three or four `keys`, that bad,

Comment: I like to do this work on two different keys. `setxkbmap -layout "us"` RALT and `setxkbmap -layout "ara"` RCTL, if you are on standard 104 US layout. In this setting, you can make sure what you are going to type.